# Shopper shelf view point calculation with webcam algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, angle

**Shelf shopper view point**

**Goal:** Find the point in the shelf where the shopper is looking at. Based on head pose angles (x,y,z) and left- and right eye (x,y) angles.
(yaw,pitch,roll)

**Given:**

- Shelf height 2m (x 1m width)

  Camera position = 1.5m inside the shelf (see picture)

  Camera Resolution = 320px * 180px

  Camera Focal length = 2.3mm

  Camera DPI = 360

  Assume Human Face height (real life) = 18cm

Head Rotation Angle (x,y,z)
Eye Rotation (left,right eye) (x,y) relative to the Head Rotation Angle

We can always get the rectangle (face) inside a picture of a picture 320px * 180px (webcam).

**Approach:**

1.) Calculate the distance first:
I used the formula:

```
Distance (cam to face) =  Human Face height in real life m * camera focal length (mm) / human face height in picture (mm)
```

with:

```
human face height in picture (mm) = 2.54  *  human face height in picture (px) / Camera DPI
```

**My Problem:**

I don’t know if it possible to solve this by somehow calculating a persons height, through knowing the camera offset height. All angles are related to the camera position, but I want to calculate the point being focused on the shelf.

The image is just a 2D example. I believe I need some translation function, rotation (head), rotation (eye) matrix to solve this?

I don’t know what is the best approach. Thank you for help.[image]